# swagger.json paths and definitions are empty. No operations defined in spec

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I am developing a .netcore web application. I am using of swagger and I've made all the necessary adjustments. Unfortunately it does not work and I just see `No operations defined in spec!` in the swagger output page.

The swagger file with `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` has the following content:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "Something"
  },
  "paths": {},
  "definitions": {}
}
```

I want to see my controllers and their actions in swagger output page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some research i was found that my problem was about using swagger along with OData in .NetCore2.1.
i found a solution for this problem.

first i added two following Nuget packages:

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations
```

then, i added following codes in Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
                foreach (var outputFormatter in 
options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => 
_.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
                {
                    outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new 
MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
                }
                foreach (var inputFormatter in 
options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().Where(_ => 
_.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
                {
                    inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new 
MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
                }
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

the, i added following code line in controllers:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
```

please note that it was worked for me but it may be need more research for eventually side effects

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add some routes in the controller.  With rest services you will need to add them separate from what was built automatically by Visual Studio.  for example
// GET: Items
[HttpGet]
[Route("/items")]
...rest of function...
this will give your swagger a reference to what it does when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I am on .Net 7 and Swagger 6.5. All I needed to do was add the following before the `builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();`

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to enable `XML Documentation file` under `project obtions => Build` tab.

Then you need to read this file through swagger so that swagger can create documentation from it.

```
private static string[] XmlCommentsFilePath
{
    get
    {
        var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

        var apiDocFile = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
        var apiPath = Path.Combine(basePath, apiDocFile);

        return new[] {apiPath};

    }
}
```

In ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{ 
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

    // add a swagger document for each discovered API version
    provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.ForEach(x => options.SwaggerDoc(x.GroupName, CreateInfoForApiVersion(x)));

    ....
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i used it before in another project and swagger automatically read all of actions without any XML file. i tried XML file from project properties->Build but it did not work

Answer (score -1):

Please add a in contoller any method like a then showing swagger methods

```
  [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<int> Get()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```