# Swagger do not show endpoints with .net core 2.2 mvc default project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, asp.net-core-2.2

It seems to me that the annotation is missing. I find all the examples for api 
 controller but not for mvc controller.

```
No operations defined in spec!
```

> {   "swagger": "2.0",   "info": {
>       "version": "v1",
>       "title": "Something"   },   "paths": {},   "definitions": {} }

I've tried these options, but they don't help me:

[swagger.json paths and definitions are empty. No operations defined in spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159987/swagger-json-paths-and-definitions-are-empty-no-operations-defined-in-spec)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case was that swagger did not know how to read the controllers.
You have to use Attributes for routing and for the return types. For example:

```
    // Add these lines to your controllers -->
    [HttpGet]                                     
    [Route("/questions/answer")]                  
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Answer), 200)]   
    // <-- End added lines :)
    public async Task<IActionResult> Active()
    {           
        return View(question);
    }
```